# Get the nearby place to certain coordinates from database

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, postgis, geoalchemy2

I created this function:

```
def get_nearby_aqi_node(lat, lng):
    distance_in_meters = 1500

    geo_wkb = func.Geometry(func.ST_GeographyFromText(
        'POINT({} {})'.format(lng, lat)))

    point = db.session.query(Hotel.hotel_name,
                             Hotel.address). \
        filter(func.ST_DFullyWithin(Hotel.location, geo_wkb, distance_in_meters)). \
        order_by(
        Comparator.distance_centroid(Hotel.location, geo_wkb)).limit(1).first()

    return point
```

but when I call it I get this error, I don't know how to solve it

```
'POINT({} {})'.format(lng, lat))) TypeError: str returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

could you tell me please where is the error

Comment: Change `'POINT({} {})'` to `'POINT({0} {1})'`, or `'POINT({lng} {lat})'.format(lng=lng, lat=lat)))`

Comment: thank u but still have the same error                                                     line 50, in get_nearby_aqi_node
    'POINT({0} {1})'.format(lng, lat))))).limit(1).first()
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)

Comment: Is the db query returning a string into `point`? Try `type(point)` to check. Could be that you're querying Hotel.hotel_name and Hotel.address into the same variable, try querying one value at a time